# How to make some column non-editable and some column editable in QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the model `MyModel : public QSqlTableModel`.
I want to forbid editing certain columns of the table. I did this using the method `flags()`, but faced with a new problem. I need to insert a row in the database, and when I cause methods `insertRow ()` and `setData ()`, the method `setData ()` returns `0` for not editable columns. Therefore, I can not fill data to inserted row.
I want to forbid editing certain columns for view, but not for the model.

Some code:

```
Qt::ItemFlags ApplicantTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.column() == 9 || index.column() == 10)
        if(index.column() == 9 && index.data() == 0)
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
        else
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    else return Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you left, I created an example widget, which shows that `setData()` even works on non editable indexes.

**Model**

```
class MyModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
    MyModel(QObject* parent = 0)
        : QStandardItemModel(parent)
    {}

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
        if(index.column() < 5)
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
        else
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }
};
```

**Table Widget**

```
// .h
class MyTableWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTableWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);

private slots:
    void onEditTextChanged(QString const&);

private:
    void initWidgets();
    void initLayout();

    QTableView* table_view_;
    MyModel*    table_model_;
    QLineEdit*  table_edit_;
};

// .cc
    MyTableWidget::MyTableWidget(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , table_view_(0)
    , table_model_(0)
    , table_edit_(0)
{
    initWidgets();
    initLayout();
}

void MyTableWidget::onEditTextChanged(QString const& text)
{
    foreach(QModelIndex index, table_view_->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
        table_model_->setData(index, text);
}

void MyTableWidget::initWidgets()
{
    table_view_ = new QTableView(this);
    table_edit_ = new QLineEdit(this);

    table_model_ = new MyModel;
    table_model_->setColumnCount(10);
    table_model_->setRowCount(10);

    for(int c = 0; c < table_model_->columnCount(); ++c) {
        for(int r = 0; r < table_model_->rowCount(); ++r) {
            table_model_->setData(table_model_->index(r,c), QString("foo"));
        }
    }

    table_view_->setModel(table_model_);

    connect(table_edit_, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString const&)),
            this, SLOT(onEditTextChanged(QString)));
}

void MyTableWidget::initLayout()
{
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(table_view_);
    layout->addWidget(table_edit_);

    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Leaving out the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag will only prevent editing by any caller that handles this flag. For instance, Qt delegates check `flags()` before they create the editor for modifying cell values. This prevents from ever calling setData(). If you call `setData()` yourself there should be no problem in editing the data.

I am assuming your error lies somewhere else. Did you overwrite `setData()` to handle `flags()`? Did you check if the ModelIndex you are handing in is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it in next way. I created delegate.

```
QWidget *StatusDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.column() == 9){
        QComboBox* editor = new QComboBox(parent);
        editor->addItem(tr("Відраховано"));
        editor->addItem(tr("Допущено"));
        editor->addItem(tr("Бюджет"));
        editor->addItem(tr("Контракт"));
        editor->setAutoFillBackground(true);
        return editor;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```